# Pyflink 1.14 table connectors - Kafka authentication

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, pyflink

I've only seen Pyflink table API examples of kafka connections which **does not** contain authentication details in the connection establishment ([doc ref](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/python/table/python_table_api_connectors/)), namely source table connection:

```
source_ddl = """
        CREATE TABLE source_table(
            a VARCHAR,
            b INT
        ) WITH (
          'connector' = 'kafka',
          'topic' = 'source_topic',
          'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka:9092',
          'properties.group.id' = 'test_3',
          'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
          'format' = 'json'
        )
        """
```

I however need to connect to kafka sources with authentication enabled. By 'interpreting' that all *property.XXX* are dedicated as kafka config, I altered the examples as follows and tested:

```py
import os
from pyflink.datastream.stream_execution_environment import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.table import TableEnvironment, EnvironmentSettings, environment_settings
from pyflink.table.table_environment import StreamTableEnvironment

KAFKA_SERVERS = 'localhost:9092'
KAFKA_USERNAME = "user"
KAFKA_PASSWORD = "XXX"
KAFKA_SOURCE_TOPIC = 'source'
KAFKA_SINK_TOPIC = 'dest'


def log_processing():

    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.add_jars("file:///opt/flink/lib_py/kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar")
    env.add_jars("file:///opt/flink/lib_py/flink-connector-kafka_2.11-1.14.0.jar")
    env.add_jars("file:///opt/flink/lib_py/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.12-1.14.0.jar")
    settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance()\
                      .in_streaming_mode()\
                      .use_blink_planner()\
                      .build()

    t_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(stream_execution_environment= env, environment_settings=settings)
    
    source_ddl = f"""
            CREATE TABLE source_table(
                Cylinders INT,
                Displacement INT,
                Horsepower INT,
                Weight INT,
                Acceleration INT,
                Model_Year INT,
                USA INT,
                Europe INT,
                Japan INT
            ) WITH (
              'connector' = 'kafka',
              'topic' = '{KAFKA_SOURCE_TOPIC}',
              'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '{KAFKA_SERVERS}',
              'properties.group.id' = 'testgroup12',
              'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'PLAIN',
              'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT',
              'properties.sasl.jaas.config' = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"{KAFKA_USERNAME}\" password=\"{KAFKA_PASSWORD}\";',
              'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
              'format' = 'json'
            )
            """

    sink_ddl = f"""
            CREATE TABLE sink_table(
                Cylinders INT,
                Displacement INT,
                Horsepower INT,
                Weight INT,
                Acceleration INT,
                Model_Year INT,
                USA INT,
                Europe INT,
                Japan INT
            ) WITH (
              'connector' = 'kafka',
              'topic' = '{KAFKA_SINK_TOPIC}',
              'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '{KAFKA_SERVERS}',
              'properties.group.id' = 'testgroup12',
              'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'PLAIN',
              'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT',
              'properties.sasl.jaas.config' = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"{KAFKA_USERNAME}\" password=\"{KAFKA_PASSWORD}\";',
              'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
              'format' = 'json'
            )
            """

    t_env.execute_sql(source_ddl)
    t_env.execute_sql(sink_ddl)

    t_env.sql_query("SELECT * FROM source_table").execute_insert("sink_table").wait()

    t_env.execute("kafka-table")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_processing()
```

By adding this job from the cli, there is no response or indication that a job in instantiated with a respective job id:

[image: cli]

> Respectively no job created when viewing flink UI

If I'm incorrectly configuring the connection, can someone please correct me, or point me to a relative source of documentation (I've googled quite a bit...)

Comment: You have specified two incompatible jar files -- you've got flink-connector-kafka compiled with scala 2.11, and flink-sql-connector-kafka for scala 2.12. Not sure it will help, but try fixing that.

Comment: Also, take a look in the job manager logs for clues.

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson, thank you so much for that catch! (sigh of embarressment) I've been testing between 2.11 and 2.12 through the course of the day, and under the impression that flink-sql-connector was the only real dependency.... so between all the tests, must've lost focus on that, and eventually got frustrated. Changing flink-connector-kafka to 2.12 certainly did resolve the issue. Any advice please on where the (1) required scala version and (2) required jar dependency for a job can be verified? I'll then be happy to write all of it up as a answer, for reference to other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, as suggested by @DavidAnderson. The code from my question works as is... just required to update the dependency jars respectively. If using Scala **2.12** and flink version **1.14**, the following dependencies are applicable (with the jar dependencies downloaded and available on you jobManager in the respective directory):

> env.add_jars("file:///opt/flink/lib_py/kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar")
>
> env.add_jars("file:///opt/flink/lib_py/flink-connector-kafka_2.12-1.14.0.jar")
>
> env.add_jars("file:///opt/flink/lib_py/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.12-1.14.0.jar")

A useful site to reference, which I found later on is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-kafka_2.12/1.14.0